# Error Handling in VBA Adding and Deleting sheets

Tags: vba, excel, error-handling

I am creating a macro where I want the final part to create a new sheet titled "Unreliability Chart" and insert a chart of the figures from the most recent calculations.

However, the second time you run the macro the sheet "Unreliability Chart" already exists and so Excel cannot create another chart with the same name. Thus after one run (or unless the user manually deletes "Unreliability Chart" after each usage) the macro errors out.

How can I create an error handler to delete "Unreliability Chart" then proceed with the rest of the code to recreate it? Below is my attempt thus far. Please help!

```
 Worksheets.Add().Name = "Unreliability Chart"
 If Error Then GoTo ErrorHandler:
 ErrorHandler:
 Sheets("Unreliability Chart").Delete
 Worksheets.Add().Name = "Unreliability Chart"
 Resume Next
```

Any idea why my code doesn't work? To me if it is run 1 everything works as it should. By run 2, I should get an error at the line Worksheets.Add().Name = "Unreliability Chart" and then go into the error handler, delete it, then recreate it, the resume with the rest of the macro. Apparently that is not the case.

Comment: You need something like `On Error GoTo ErrorHandler` **before** statement that can cause an error.

Comment: That worked out excellently! It completely does what I want it to...however, is there a way to have VBA run the code but not give a pop up window that reads, "Data may exist in the sheet(s) selected for deletion. To permanently delete the data, press Delete" and just to delete the data?

Comment: Also thank you very much

Comment: Try adding this before deleting - `Application.DisplayAlerts = False` then at the very end, `Application.DisplayAlerts = True`.

Comment: Exactly what Bat... BruceWayne said. Also, notice that the line `Worksheets.Add().Name = "Unreliability Chart"` will add new worksheet and AFTER this will try to change the name (and only the second operation will cause error). This means that you will have two new worksheets every time.

Comment: Amazing! Thank you all very much, I am able to move forward now.